# What is the recommended way of accessing a variable from a different reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the recommended way of accessing a variable from a different reducer?

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './reducers/main';
import configReducer from './reducers/config';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    main:mainReducer,
    config:configReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

I have two different reducer and I have an action inside mainReducer where I want to access a variable inside configReducer. What is the proper way to do this with Redux?

```
export default function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE_ACTIVE":
      //need to check variable options inside configReducer
      default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say variable you mean global state right?

Comment: A variable inside the reducer's store.

Comment: Can you post the code of `configReducer` and the variable you would want to access.
I think by variable you mean state which is modified using `configReducer` i.e global state.

Comment: the variable is inside store.config, it's something like store.config.options. I want to access it inside mainReducer instead of configReducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a reducer just returns a `slice` of the global state i.e `store`.

If you are using a middleware like `thunk`, you can share the data like so:

```
export function updateActive(params) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { config } = getState(); // the part you want to access.

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_ACTIVE,
      options: config.options,
      params,
    });
  };
}
```

So you get all the data in the `action` itself and then dispatch with the ACTION_TYPE.

You can read more on sharing state between reducers on :

1. https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers/
2. https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate

Comment: What if I don't have a middleware like thunk?

Comment: const store = createStore(rootReducer);
const getStore = () => {return store;}
export default store;
so I can do this? What if I don't have a middleware?

Comment: @gosa If you aren't using any middleware i.e not even `thunk`, then you can directly import `store` into the reducer and do `store.getState()`. 
But I highly recommend using `thunk`, you will find sufficient information in the two links I shared in answer.

Comment: I get: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store. in React 16 and Redux 4

Comment: @gosa You should call store.getState(), when you are dispatching, not inside the switch cases of reducer.
 Basically your action will have the payload as `config.options`